# How to adjust the height of range depends on the value?

Tags: css, range, slider

I am looking for a help to adjust the height of range slider depends on the target value?

As much as the user will drag the ball of the range, the left side's height will increase. It will be like filling the range. Could you help me how I can achieve this like in the UI has attached to this post.

[This is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEOP3.png)

Here is my code below:

HTML:

```
<div class="range-container">
      <input type="range" name="range" id="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" />
      <label for="range">DRAG</label>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.range-container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#range {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 90px auto;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#range:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: var(--theme-col);
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-top: -4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: please post your code also

Comment: If you've got time, you might try revising CSS/JS on one of these to fit your needs:   
https://codepen.io/dragos193/pen/QrqGgV   or    
https://codepen.io/brandonmcconnell/pen/oJBVQW